# Why apt doesnt add software to the PATH?

Tags: bash, console

I was comparing `snap` and `apt` installation methods. First of all I tried with `snap`:

1. `sudo apt update` - I am not sure, wether it have any sence to update and upgrade repos when using snap, but did that anyway
2. `sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo snap find kdenlive` - to assure, there is a right snap
4. `sudo snap install kdenlive`
5. `kdenlive` - and it starts the application
6. close the aplication from GUI
7. `sudo snap remove kdenlive`
8. `sudo apt autoremove` - not sure here either wether to use this with snap, but did it anyway

Then I proceeded with `apt` function:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo apt list kdenlive` - to look for kdenlive pack, but here I didnt understand the output
4. `sudo apt install kdenlive`
5. `kdenlive` - leads to en error (`bash: /snap/bin/kdenlive: No such file or directory`)
6. `./kdenlive` - leads to the same error, I can only run the application from GUI
7. Than I unistall the same way as above

So why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your shell – bash – keeps a memory cache of path lookups. After you've run `kdenlive` once and it was resolved to `/snap/bin/kdenlive`, that particular shell process will *directly* go to `/snap/bin/kdenlive` from that point, regardless of what $PATH says.

If a program has been moved from one location to another, you need to run `hash -r` or restart the shell in order to pick up the change.